# routeResult.Status in windows phone 8.1 app keeps giving invalidcredentials errormessage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm fairly new to programming in XAML and I'm making an application for school as assignment on windows phone 8.1 emulator with a MapControl.

Yesterday I wanted to draw a route and followed this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631250.aspx, and it worked fine. Today I ran it again but it keeps giving me the errormessage 'InvalidCredentials' with the routeResult.Status. I have no idea why it's giving this error.

This is the code that I use:

```
public async void SetRouteDirectionsBreda()
    {
        string beginLocation = "Willemstraat 17 Breda";
        string endLocation = "Reigerstraat 2 Breda";

        MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(beginLocation, map.Center);
        MapLocation begin = result.Locations.First();

        result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(endLocation, map.Center);
        MapLocation end = result.Locations.First();

        List<Geopoint> waypoints = new List<Geopoint>();
        waypoints.Add(begin.Point);
        // Adding more waypoints later
        waypoints.Add(end.Point);

        MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(waypoints);

        Debug.WriteLine(routeResult.Status); // DEBUG

        if (routeResult.Status == MapRouteFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
            viewOfRoute.RouteColor = Colors.Blue;
            viewOfRoute.OutlineColor = Colors.Black;

            map.Routes.Add(viewOfRoute);

            await map.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(routeResult.Route.BoundingBox, null, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(routeResult.Status.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your map service token in the xaml page and add your application id to the package manifest.

Everything you need to know about adding mapservicetoken to your app can be found in the link below.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx

Comment: Do I really have to buy a token before I can actually use it? It worked fine one day...

Comment: Looks like tokens are free for students! Thanks!

Comment: I have same problem, added every token and Id, and getting this error on some locations only, others working and showing route also